# Using PDO to protect from SQL injection

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have been using a require_once directive in my code to require a script ('`connect.php`') that connects to the MySQL database I am using. I am now converting my code to PDO prepared statements, as suggested by many users here on SO.

Do I ditch the `require_once` and put the PDO connection in each of my scripts one-by-one? Or can I simply replace the data in my '`connect.php`' script with PDO implementation?

Comment: Replace the `connect.php` contents with a valid PDO connection

Comment: While you are developing the amendments to use PDO you can have BOTH connections in the `connect.php` and then old and new code will work

Comment: That depends on how you currently compose your queries. But most likely you currently have something like `mysql_query('SELECT * FROM \`a_table\` WHERE ID='.$_GET['id'])`  so you need to update all of your queries into a form that contains placeholders for your variable so that it looks like `SELECT * FROM \`a_table\` WHERE ID=?` or `SELECT * FROM \`a_table\` WHERE ID=:id` so you need to update all of your code where you create your queries.

Comment: @t.niese yes, this is the task I am saddled with now; at this early stage I do not have much to amend so I feel lucky.

Comment: @RiggsFolly thank you!